Delivery of packets to the correct web servers when they run in same machines
For example, I run two web servers in a single machine (only a single NIC available).
They use different ports (let us say: 1200 and 1201)
Now when a client (say from a mobile device or a browser from a laptop), tries to reach those web servers.
Either the servers are reached by typing http address or IP address in the browser; but port number is NOT given along.
In this case, how the packets are delivered to the correct servers since the port numbers are not given in the address?
I am aware that incoming packets will be delivered to the correct browser processes since the packets contain client IP address along with port number.
Thanks!

They can be on a single (the default) port.

If the port number is not provided in an HTTP URL, user agent clients like web browsers will default to using port 443 for HTTPS and port 80 for HTTP.

You can use  a reverse proxy on the server Nginx or Haproxy etc. to manage tjat part.

The link by @KamilMaciorowski is the right answer here.
